# error with dynGraph package

Tags: r

The `acp` object in the R code below is the ouput of a `PCA()` call. Do you have any idea about the cause of the error ?

```
> library(dynGraph)
Loading required package: rJava
> dynGraph(acp)
Error in .jinit(classpath = paste(dir, "dynGraph.jar", sep = "")) :
  Cannot create Java virtual machine (-4)
```

**EDIT:** Below is an example producing another error:

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(dynGraph)

D <- scan()
3 -2 -1
2 -1 -3
1 2 -3
-3 1 2
-2 0 3

D <- as.data.frame(matrix(D, byrow=TRUE, ncol=3))
names(D) <- c("x","y","z")
rownames(D) <- LETTERS[1:nrow(D)]

acp <- PCA(D,  
    scale.unit=FALSE,
    ncp=2, graph=FALSE)

dynGraph(acp)

> dynGraph(acp)
Error in .jcall(obj, , "addVal", annot[1, 1], tab) : 
  java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredTextImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
```

**EDIT:** In fact dynGraph works well with the previous example when simply typing:

```
dynGraph(D)
```

So I suspect the errors are due to a bad practice ?

**EDIT:** Below is the sessionInfo() output:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dynGraph_1.05        rJava_0.9-3          FactoMineR_1.20      scatterplot3d_0.3-33 cluster_1.14.2      
[6] lattice_0.20-10      ellipse_0.3-7       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.1  tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: This is a problem you are having with your JVM. Usually, your `JAVA_HOME` variable isn't set correctly. Do you have Java installed, and are you environment variables set correctly?

Comment: @nograpes Hi. I don't know how to set environment variables. And is it possible without administrator privileges ?

Comment: I think Java is installed because the JGR and Deducer packages work well.

Comment: If you give us a very small sample of what `acp` looks like with `dput(acp)`, then we can try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @nograpes I have added an example... but in fact it yields another error !

Comment: @nograpes I have just checked right now that the example dynGraph(wine) given in the help page work well!

Comment: Your posted code works for me. Try posting your `sessionInfo()`. I am using dynGraph 0.99100403.